# Writing to a file using a users input in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a user input to a word file for my troubleshooting system. However it doesn't write to the file and ends the code. I am trying to make it so that if the user inputs 'no' twice, then it should follow the following code:

```
 if count == 2:
     f = open('problems.txt', 'w')
     ui = ("What is the problem?")
     f.write(ui)
```

Instead the code ends.

Here's the code:

```
count = 0
while count != 2:
    a = input("Is your phone broken?")
    if a == "no":
        count = count + 1
    if count == 2:
        f = open('problems.txt', 'w')
        ui = ("What is the problem?")
        f.write(ui)
```

But the code doesn't open the file and write to the file, the program just ends after the user inputs no. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong? Could anyone help me please.

Comment: Is the indentation wrong?

Comment: lines after `while` statement should be indented.

Comment: Why the use of `()` in your ui text? have you tried to remove it? Write receives a String, and maybe those parenthesis are casting your string to other type?

Comment: @TalesPádua: The use of parentheses without a trailing comma does not change the type.

Comment: No the indentation is fine on my code I just wrote it wrong sorry

Comment: what python version are you using? 2 or 3, if you're using 2, try raw_input() instead of input()

Comment: That code works fine for me.  After saying `no` twice, it writes to the file.  I can open the file elsewhere and the text is displayed.  You may want to put a newline character at the end of the string, though.

Comment: Please edit your post to show the indentation as it appears in your actual code, as written the `if count == 2` is inside your `while` loop

Comment: It is in the while loop

Comment: Are you sure your using the same code as me? If so what python version are you using zondo?

Comment: I also tested using Python 2.7 and changing input to raw_input. It worked fine

Comment: Did it save on the text file?

Comment: Yes, it did worked fine

Comment: What that's so weird

Comment: @TalesPádua i've uninstalled python 3.5.1 and am cuurentley installing 3.4.3 as I'm more familiar with it and see if the same code works on it

Comment: @zondo are you sure your not taking the piss? I tried it on 3.4.3 and it still ends the code after me inputting no twice

Comment: No worries I just had to close the file sorry for all the trouble

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2.x, use `raw_input`.

```
count = 0
while count != 2:
    a = raw_input("Is your phone broken?")
    print a
    if a == "no":
        count = count + 1
    if count == 2:
        f = open('problems.txt', 'w')
        ui = ("What is the problem?")
        f.write(ui)
```